# Alternative Syntax for an XPath in nokogiri, parsing an ODF

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri, odf

I have a pretty straightforward ODF document that I want to parse with nokogiri.

The XML looks like this:

```
<office:body>
<office:text>
    <text:sequence-decls>
        ...
    </text:sequence-decls>
    <text:section text:name="categorylevel1" text:style-name="Sect1">
        <text:p text:style-name="Title">[CATEGORY_LEVEL_1_NAME]</text:p>
    </text:section>
</office:text>
```

Currently I'm trying to select the `categorylevel1` section of the document. The library I'm using generates the XPath automatically and yields
`".//text:section[@text:name='categorylevel1']"`
which is correct. Now the problem is the library (nokogiri) seems to accept this path under MRI but not under JRuby (throws a SyntaxError). Apparently the Java version of the library does not support namespace attributes.

Is there an alternative way to reference the section of the document? For example just by using the `text:name` attribute? Is there a way to ignore the namespace? The section's `text:name` attribute  value will be unique for the whole document so miss-referencing would not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there an alternative way to reference the section of the document? For example just by using the text:name attribute?"

You can ignore element name by using `*`, this way you can reference the element *just by using the text:name attribute* :

```
.//*[@text:name='categorylevel1']
```

> "Is there a way to ignore the namespace?"

You can use `local-name()` to ignore namespaces. For example, to filter element by `text:name` attribute value while ignoring the attribute's namespace :

```
.//*[@*[local-name()='name' and .='categorylevel1']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples. The second path did the job! However the first one also throws a syntaxerror. Support for namespaces in Java must be really limited.